# Adding tags to selection

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am using this Javascript to effect the following changes in my selected text:

```
    function formatText(el,tag){
var selectedText = document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz
if (selectedText == "")
{return false}
var newText='"#28'+tag+'"'+selectedText+'"#28'+tag+'"';
if(document.selection){    //IE
document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
}
else{   //Moz
el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
}
}
```

However, i want the new tags to only be visible in another textarea not the one where I actually do the selecting. In this case I have 2 Text areas, one is called "message_text" the other is called "message" ... I iwll input and select text in "message_text" but any changes made to the selection must only reflect in the "message" text area.

At present I have tried this:

```
<button type="button" value="D" onclick="formatText(message,'D')" class="blue">D</button>
```

But this only works if I have selected anytnin in the "message" text area.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you created a minimal code example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the javascript code:

```js
function formatText(el_from, el_to, tag) {
    var selectedText = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : el_from.value.substring(el_from.selectionStart, el_from.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz

    if (selectedText == "") {
        return false;
    }

    var start_index = el_to.value.indexOf(selectedText);
    var sel_t_len = selectedText.length;
    var copy_selText = el_to.substring(start_index, sel_t_len);

    var newText='"#28'+tag+'"'+copy_selText+'"#28'+tag+'"';

    el_to.value = el_to.value.substring(0, start_index) + newText + el_to.value.substring(sel_t_len, el_to.value.length);
}
```

Then You can call it like this:

```
<button type="button" value="D" onclick="formatText(document.getElementById('message_text'), document.getElementById('message'),'D')" class="blue">D</button>
```

PS: I'm not sure about `document.getElementById` - haven't used it for years since using jQuery... You should convert to jQuery, too... You would not noeed to solve JS for IE or FF or Chrome, etc - jQuery handles this by itself...

**EDIT :** OK, I did a little customization and it should fit to Your needs...

Comment: Thank you shadyyx, this works great, just one problem though, any new selection overrides the previous, so if my first selection changed was:
`this is "#28B"BOLD TEXT"#28B"` and then I click another selection change `"#28F"this is"#28F" BOLD TEXT` when it shoudl be `"#28F"this is"#28F" "#28B"BOLD TEXT"#28B"` .. any ideas how I can free the last result?

Comment: Currently this will not work unless You keep the changes within the textarea where You select the text... Since some few characters are always added into the second textarea the substring functions (especially the start and end indexes) will not fit the text in the first textarea... Why don't You want to change the text in the first textarea?

Comment: @user1395580 I have edited the code, try it now (maybe it would need a little modification everywhere where `sel_t_len` is maybe there should be `sel_t_len+1`.

Comment: @user1395580 Please, accept the answer if it was helpful and solved Your problem. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks shadyyx, unfortunately the edit doesn't do anything. But you have put me on the right path, I really appreciate it. PD: Sorry for the late acceptance of your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry for not being more helpful but glad I'd helped a little bit...