# Adding html/any tags to either side of selection - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

## Adding HTML/any tags to either side of selection - Javascript

#### The problem:

After creating a textarea box in my PHP/html file I wished to add a little more functionality and decided to make an textarea that can use formatting, for example

```
<textarea>
This is text that was inserted. <b>this text was selected and applied a style
via a button<b>
</textarea>
```

It doesn't matter what the tags are, (could be bubbles for all that I care due to the fact the PHP script, on receiving the `$_POST` data will automatically apply the correct tags with the tag as the style ID. **Not relevant**)

#### The Question/s

- How can I create this feature using javascript?
- Are there any links that may help?
- And can, if there is information, can you explain it?

**EDIT**: Other close example but not quite is stackoverflow's editor and note that I do not wish to use 3rd party scripts, this is a **learning process** for me.
The tags that are inserted in the text are saved to a database and then when the page is requested the PHP replaces the tags with the style ID. If there is a work around not involving 3rd party scripts please suggest

And for the anti-research skeptics on a google search, little was found that made sense and there was  **Previous Research on SOF:**
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752123/how-to-make-an-online-html-editor
- [Adding tags to selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684368/adding-tags-to-selection)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not use one of the open source alternatives such as CKEditor or TinyMCE?

Comment: I'd check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765381/how-do-i-wrap-a-text-selection-from-window-getselection-getrangeat0-with-an

Comment: @Rob I have added my in the description, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @Blender Thats interesting that it didn't come up in my own search. Although the user provide answers, they do not fully explain it. Its half of my I made my question

Comment: @Blender Ill do some more research with your link though its seems you might have provided me with some useful infomation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<textarea>` elements cannot contain special markup, only values.  You can't apply any styling in a textarea.

What you'll need to do is fake everything that a text box would normally do, including drawing a cursor.  This is a *lot* of work, as hackattack said.

You can do a lot if you grab jQuery and start poking around.  Toss a `<div>` tag out there with an ID for ease and start hacking away.

I've never made one personally, but there is a lot to it.  HTML5's contentEditable can maybe get you a good chunk of the way there:  http://html5demos.com/contenteditable/

If you want to pass this data back to the server, you'll need to grab the innerHTML of the container and slap that into a hidden input upon submission of your form.

Here's other some things you can check out if you're just messing around:

- tabindex HTML attribute, to get focus in your box from tabbing
- jQuery.focus() http://api.jquery.com/focus/, to determine when someone clicks in your box
- cursor: text in CSS for looks http://wap.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp
- jQuery.keypress() http://api.jquery.com/keypress/, or similar for grabbing keystrokes

**Edit: I think I *completely* misunderstood**

If you're not looking for a rich text editor, and just want some helper buttons for code, maybe selectionStart and selectionEnd is what you're after.  I don't know what the browser support is, but it's working in Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/5yXsd/

Comment: Let me know if that edit was closer to what you were after or not and I'll remove the irrelevant section of my post.

Comment: This post was very useful, providing links and an example and your edit was critical.

Comment: Now how can with your example add extra elements? I believe I understand what you have done so far

Comment: Thanks you very much, with you help I made a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5yXsd/19/

Answer (score 0):

you can not do anything beside basic formatting inside a texarea. If you want complex formatting, look into setting a div's contentEditable attribute to true. Or you can make a wysisyg editor, but that is a big project. I strongly suggest using 3rd party code on this one.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I understand that this may turn out to be a bigger project than originally expected but I would like to give it a bash never the less. If nobody else writes an answer that may point me in a right direction, I may have to forfeit and accept your answer, but for the time being I wish to stand my ground. Ill certainly look into `contentEditable`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would love to point you in the right direction. You say you are looking for something similar to the stackoverflow editor? It looks like stack overflow uses an editor called wmd (http://code.google.com/p/wmd/). Could you look at that code and break it apart to find what your looking for?

Comment: Ill have alook, heres a link http://s11.postimage.org/fvifduomp/textinput.png hope it give an idea

Comment: do you want the formatted text to show inside the box as you type or do you want to apply the format later? If you just want to wrap selected  text in tags and then format later, you can do that a lot easier

Comment: yes I should have made it clearer, this is want I would like to do, as I can add some ajax and php to make a live preview

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using the iframe to implement the WYSIWYG effect. 
There is a property in `iframe` called `designMode`

See here for more
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

Also there is a lightweight example maybe you would like to take a look:
http://code.google.com/p/rte-light/source/browse/trunk/jquery.rte.js